# Maven - automatically add child module as dependency to other child modules

Tags: maven, circular-dependency

I have the following parent-child hierarchy:

```
+ parent: pom
    - common: jar
    - app1: war
    - app2: war
    - ...
```

Is it possible to have the module `common` automatically included as a dependency in each `appX` module? That is, without having to manually add it to the dependencies in each `appX` project. Adding it as a depdency to `parent` will introduce a circular dependency.

Comment: So you are saying app1 and app2 wars are depending on common jar ?

Comment: Just add it as a dependency to the child modules which use it and that's it..how should Maven know you would like to do such a thing?